# I'm having trouble finding an available switch to match a schematic. Is it possible?

Tags: digital-logic, switches

I'm having trouble finding a 4P3T switch for the circuit below, [credited to David Mikeska](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/562248/can-two-on-off-valves-be-independently-or-concurrently-switched-with-my-hardware), which I believe to be described as follows in a contact configuration table you'd commonly see on a datasheet. Is this table correctly described, and are there any recommendations about the switch configuration itself? This doesn't seem to be a commonly available configuration when compared to catalog offerings.

L             C             R

X             O             X

O             X             X

X             O             X

O             X             X

Thanks

EDIT: I am seeking an industrial selector-type solution, such as a 23 or 30mm panel mount switch. Here is a [link](https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/738143e514994234de854c222b3f1a90.pdf) to an example product sheet to show how their configurations are published. On page 22 of this document (Cat Pg #741) you'll see the available configuration of a 4NO contact Selector switch with operator positions listed. These positions don't quite match what I need, the configuration listed above. I think I may be overcomplicating this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I don't seek a specific product recommendation. More value would be added in understanding how to reconstruct the switch design, if necessary, to accomodate the more generic modular solutions offered by manufacturers.

[image: switch]

Comment: Pick a vendor such as mouser.com, look under electromechanical --> switches, filter by "contact form", voila.

Comment: Do you want to take a bog-standard 4P3T switch and wire it up to match the schematic, or do you want a switch that's internally wired?  Because I just checked, and there's still lots of choices out there in 4P3T switches.

Comment: It will help if you update your question to say something about the voltage and current requirements, the environment, the size, budget, etc.  Although product recommendations are off-topic here, this looks like it might be an industrial environment, so there are plenty of choices from manufacturers like Electroswitch or Rockwell.  Of course these will be costly.

Comment: @Theodore I updated the post with a link to an example switch that would suffice. Those are the configurations I typically browse through when looking, but can't seem to find one that fits the bill.

Comment: @TimWescott I was curious about that. If I had, say, simply 12 terminals on a switch as depicted in the schematic (SW2's 4 poles x 3 output options each) this would be fairly easy, and just a little extra wiring. But it seems the manufacturers of these industrial selector switches prefer a modular approach with a configuration process that uses decks or some kind of cam to only provide a certain configuration of output! It's really frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

If you can tolerate a rotary switch then it's easy.

[image]

*Figure 1. A 12-contact rotary switch by Lorlin.*

These switches have 12 contacts around the edge and 1, 2, 3, 4 or 6 contacts on the inner ring to make (respectively) 12-way, 6-way, 4-way, 3-way or 2-way switches. (You have to order the right version. You want a 3-way.)

There's a washer with a stop-tab that is inserted on the threaded boss to limit the number of positions it can be turned to.

Variations of this type of switch have wafers which can be stacked to give a wider variety of switching arrangements. These were popular on old radios and oscilloscopes.

Comment: They're not available in the variety that they were back in the "old radio" days (we've gotten too good with relays and microprocessors and such), but there's still a good selection.